# Design MongoDB schema to make many fields queryable

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to design a schema in MongoDB. In this, there are many fields ~6 fields and fields in subdocuments ~3 which I can query. Is there any way to make it queryable quicker then seq scan? I could have used index but the fields query can come in any order and also I don't want to make compound index for every combination.

Is there any way I can design this kind of schema?

Comment: You could change to use the attribute pattern - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern

Comment: I thought of this but then I found Atlas search. Would that be useful in my use case. Which would be more better in performance and lesser cost.

Comment: Sounds good!  Looks like you have a solution...

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on which way to go in or have you tried atlas search?

Comment: Atlas search is a powerful search engine based on Apache Lucene.  It will likely be able to serve all your various search needs in one index.  Because it is an external search system the data must be replicated to it.  This can cause a latency between when data was inserted vs. when data is searched - usually within several seconds.  Also, the Atlas search identifies the documents, then the query engine must find the resulting documents to return them.  This is an extra step which usually costs about 20-30ms.  If you are OK with these limitations then Atlas Search is a good option.

Comment: What do you mean by External System? Is it in a different cluster, any doc? How it is different from regular index?

Comment: Atlas search is a service installed on your Atlas cluster and sits next to the mongo processes and services.  But since it is another process it must have data replicated to it.  The query engine detects an Atlas Search query when the user presents an aggregate pipeline with a stage of $search.  This instructs the request to be sent to the Atlas Search process.  The results of the search is input to the ordinary database process.  Atlas Search is drastically different from ordinary indexes as it is based on Apache Lucene.  It has its own query language and configuration.